# discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): from trying to dm some discord members

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My code bans a member and also dms them, I tested it on 3 discord members on my server striped of any roles only one of them gets the dm and the rest don't.

This is the error:

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Missing permission...
```

And this is my code:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, content: str = ("10")):
    if content == ("10"):
        print ("oof")
    else:
        if member.top_role < ctx.message.author.top_role:
            msg = "{} has been banned for {}".format(member, content)
            await client.ban(member)
            await client.send_message(member, "You have been banned for {}".format(content))
            await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
        else:
            msg = "Sorry but you do not have the permissions {} as {} is a higher role than you".format(ctx.message.author.mention)
            await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
```

I also tried again and it worked on another one but still not the other two users.

[image]

Also the permissions error just spits out if any error happens, I still get that FORBIDDEN error on the console and both of the members dont have the bot blocked.

Comment: Which line is generating the error?  Try switching the `send_message` and the `ban`.  I wouldn't expect you to be able to message a banned member.  It may be that you don't have sufficient permissions on the bot to ban people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the bot has the user in a mutual server or the DM function is placed before the actual bot.ban, you won't be able to send the DM to the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused because either the user blocked the bot, or they don't share mutual servers.

The permission error is because you most likely made a command similar to the following>

```
@client.event
async def on_error(ctx, error):

    ctx.send("Sorry, but you do not have the permissions")
```

That command makes it so when there is ANY ERROR, post this message: "sorry, but you do not have the permissions".

If you want to make it ONLY WHEN THERE IS A PERMISSION ERROR, I advise you to change that command to the following:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(":redTick: You don't have permission to use this command.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("An error has occured, it has been logged in the bot terminal.  
        Please check if you have typed in the correct command.")
        raise error
```

Enjoy your day!